# Post with latest comment on top of index page - Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to display post with the latest made comment in it, on top of page. And every Post *has many* comments and many Comments *belong to* one post.

Here is my index method from Posts controller

```
def index
    @posts = Post.all.order("posts.created_at desc")
    def new
        @post = Post.new
    end
end
```

I looked through Rails docs and found .order and .where methods, and I think those two methods are the solution to my problem but I am not sure how to use it

Comment: did you solved your issue ?

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
@posts = Post.joins(:comments).order("comments.created_at DESC")
```

Comment: This duplicates posts for some reason

Comment: Post the out put what you got in `@posts`

Answer (score 1):

```
def index
    @posts = Post.all.order("created_at DESC")
    @latest_post = @posts.first
end
```

**update**

I interpreted word comments as posts.

**update 2**

First you need to find the latest comment:

```
@latest_comment = Comment.all.order('created_at DESC').first
```

Having that, you can extract the ID of the Post to which this comment belong:

```
post_id = latest_comment.post_id
```

Now you have the latest comment and the respective post's id. I would modify index page like this:

```
def index
   @posts = Post.all.order("created_at DESC")
   @latest_comment = Comment.all.order('created_at DESC').first
   @post_of_latest_comment = Post.find(@latest_comment.post_id)
end
```

I am not sure what do you mean by displaying it on top, but I am pretty sure with this code you can do it in your view.

**update 3**
In your view, you hsould have something like this:

```
<h1>Top comment</h1>
<%= @latest_comment.text %>
```

By `.text`I mean some attribute of model Comment wich contains the content of the comment, plain text. If you need more help with this, show what atributes your Post and Coment model have.

Comment: @micumune In your code you did **two** things: 1) Saved in `@posts` all posts in ordered way 2) Created a new instance of Post. In my example I repeated the step number 1, but my second step is different. I actually find the latest posts. Aren´t you trying to get "post with latest made comment" ?

Comment: Yes but when I go to index page lastly created post is on top not post with latest comment in it

Comment: Every Post has many comments ? and each comment belongs only to one post ? I am asking this because it is not clear to me if the comment is an attribute of Post or a separate model.

Comment: Every Post has many comments and many comments belong to one post...Look at it like a forum Post is basically thread and comments are reply's.I hope this helps

Comment: Where I need to place 
latest_comment = Comment.all.order('created_at DESC').first
  post_id = @latest_comment.post_id

Comment: those two lines go to your index method. I updated the answer again.

Comment: I get error saying undefined local variable or method `latest_comment' in this line @post_of_latest_comment = Post.find(latest_comment.post_id)

Comment: this symbol is missing '@'. It should be @latest_comment and not latest_comment.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a modified line from **Pitabas Prathal**:

```
Post.joins(:comments).order("comments.created_at DESC").group('post_id')
```

where post_id is the foreign key in the Comment model from the Post model. It worked fine for me :)